# GraphQL not working on Geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I try to make **GraphQL** work on Geth (version 1.10.1-stable) without any success.

I try to run this query, but I only get 404.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "query": "{syncing{startingBlock currentBlock highestBlock}}"}' http://localhost:8545/graphql
```

...also tried port 8547 and without `/graphql` but no success. Am I missing something?

I run Geth using the following config:

```
# config.toml
...
[Node]
IPCPath = "geth.ipc"
HTTPHost = "127.0.0.1"
HTTPPort = 8545
HTTPCors = ["*"]
HTTPVirtualHosts = ["localhost"]
HTTPModules = ["web3", "eth"]
WSHost = "127.0.0.1"
WSPort = 8546
WSOrigins = ["*"]
WSPathPrefix = "/ws"
WSModules = ["web3", "eth"]
GraphQLVirtualHosts = ["localhost"]
GraphQLCors = ["*"]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch the node with `--graphql`